# Angular 2 : transpilation and start cmds failed

Tags: javascript, npm, angular

I'm new with Angular 2 and I have some errors while launching a basic app. I just create a new component and boostrap it. Nothing more.

Here is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ngrx/store": "^1.3.3",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.9",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.24",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.7",
    "typings": "^0.7.5"
  }
}
```

I have the latests versions of node & npm. I also installed globally the devDependencies.

My error log when I tried to npm run tsc:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'tsc' ]
2 info using npm@3.7.3
3 info using node@v5.8.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretsc', 'tsc', 'posttsc' ]
5 info lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~pretsc: angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~pretsc: no script for pretsc, continuing
7 info lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~tsc: angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~tsc: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~tsc: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;D:\__\mdev\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\cmder\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\share\vim\vim74;C:\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5;C:\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;C:\Ruby22-x64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\;C:\Users\cflodrops\Downloads\windows-7.0.0\windrush;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin;C:\Users\cflodrops\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\ProgramData\Drush\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Drush\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Drush\Php;C:\Program Files (x86)\Drush\cwRsync\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;\\sdossier.groupe.zzroot.com\dossiers$\cflodrops\AppData\npm;C:\cmder
10 verbose lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~tsc: CWD: D:\__\mdev
11 silly lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~tsc: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'tsc' ]
12 silly lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~tsc: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
13 info lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~tsc: Failed to exec tsc script
14 verbose stack Error: angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 tsc: `tsc`
14 verbose stack Exit status 2
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:239:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:185:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
15 verbose pkgid angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd D:\__\mdev
17 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "tsc"
19 error node v5.8.0
20 error npm  v3.7.3
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 tsc: `tsc`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 tsc script 'tsc'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     tsc
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

And when I execute npm start:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'lite' ]
2 info using npm@3.7.3
3 info using node@v5.8.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prelite', 'lite', 'postlite' ]
5 info lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~prelite: angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~prelite: no script for prelite, continuing
7 info lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;D:\__\mdev\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;D:\__\mdev\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\cmder\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\share\vim\vim74;C:\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5;C:\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;C:\Ruby22-x64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\;C:\Users\cflodrops\Downloads\windows-7.0.0\windrush;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin;C:\Users\cflodrops\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\ProgramData\Drush\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Drush\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Drush\Php;C:\Program Files (x86)\Drush\cwRsync\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;\\sdossier.groupe.zzroot.com\dossiers$\cflodrops\AppData\npm;C:\cmder
10 verbose lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: CWD: D:\__\mdev
11 silly lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'lite-server' ]
12 silly lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: Failed to exec lite script
14 verbose stack Error: angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:239:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:185:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
15 verbose pkgid angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd D:\__\mdev
17 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "lite"
19 error node v5.8.0
20 error npm  v3.7.3
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite script 'lite-server'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     lite-server
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work either with nodejs 5. but with version 0.12.xx works fine. You can use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install and use/try different node versions

Comment: I'd try it with 4.x.x first, as those versions have long term support - the 0.12.x releases are really old, dating from before the merger with io.js. I really highly doubt the Angular devs would make it a requirement to have to roll back that far.

Comment: It's a pain to downgrade node version on Windows.
I've installer the 4.4.0, and get the same probleme as above :/

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the issue comes from lite-server. I've decided to install http-server and change my package.json like that :

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run http\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc -p .",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w -p .",
    "lite": "nano-server",
    "http": "http-server -p 3000 -a 127.0.0.1 -o",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ngrx/store": "^1.3.3",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.9",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.24",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.7",
    "typings": "^0.7.5"
  }
}
```

And it works. Thanks for your help !